# Programmatically move category in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have 3000+ products in a brand category. How do I programmatically move brand to brand collection?

If I move in the backend it will take some time. How do I move?

Comment: is `brand collection` a category or else?

Comment: Ya Both are category only

Comment: have you tried with sql Query...?

Comment: How to move using sql

Comment: please see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this easily ***using a MySQL query.***

As per as my suggestion this is the best way.

Magento saves product-category associations in the ***catalog_category_product***  table.

### Steps

**Step 1:** Take a backup of the database. Mainly the ***catalog_category_product*** table.

**Step 2:**  Run the below query for *moving products from the old category to the new category*.

> SELECT {NEW_CAT_ID} cat, `product_id`, `position` FROM
>   catalog_category_product WHERE `category_id`= {OLD_CAT_ID} AND
>   product_id NOT IN (
>       SELECT `product_id`
>       FROM catalog_category_product
>       WHERE category_id = {NEW_CAT_ID}));

Suppose, your ***new category id is 7***, and ***the old category id is 4***.

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_product(

    SELECT 7 cat, `product_id`, `position`
    FROM catalog_category_product
    WHERE `category_id` = 4
    AND product_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT  `product_id`
        FROM catalog_category_product
        WHERE category_id = 7
    )
);
```

**Step 3:** Delete records from the old category using a MySQL query:

> Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id={OLD_CAT_ID};

**Example:**

```
Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id=4;
```

Comment: ok i will try it .

Comment: Hey it's moving one category to another category but it not display in front end i checked  inventory, stock status everthing is ok but not display in front end\

Comment: after that old category product also not display frontend

Comment: Please reindex from admin>system>configuration.... specifically category products

Comment: step are removing the product from old category

Comment: it automatically turn into disable and out of stock  for both new and old category

Comment: I have check in my system.... it working properly..may any extension will do.. May other issue.it better to check at this steps on default magento.... then you can understand..

Comment: ok i will check my default magento pack

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have the category you want to move called `$category` and the category you want to be the parent of `$category`...Let's call that `$parentCategory`.
you can do this from code:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category')->changeParent($category, $parentCategory);
```

This will make `$category` a child of `$parentCategory` but it will add it as the first child of `$parentCategory`.
If you want to move `$category` after a certain chilc of `$parentCategory` you need to do this:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category')->changeParent($category, $parentCategory, $afterChildId);
```

where `$afterChildId` is the id of a child category of `$parentCategory`.

Here is an example.
You have this tree

```
 - A
 - B
   - C
   - D
```

And you want to make A a child of B.

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category')->changeParent($instanceOfCategoryA, $instanceOfCategoryB);
```

will result in

```
 - B
   - A
   - C
   - D
```

and

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category')->changeParent($instanceOfCategoryA, $instanceOfCategoryB, $idOfCategoryC);
```

will result in

```
 - B
   - C
   - A
   - D
```

Comment: can you please give the full code and tell me where i have to use this code

Comment: you can create a module and do this in the install script of the module. Here is a tutorial on how to do that: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query of Amit Bera  for Magento 2

```
 INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position)
    SELECT 100, `product_id`, `position`
    FROM catalog_category_product
    WHERE `category_id` = 726
    AND product_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT  `product_id`
        FROM catalog_category_product
        WHERE category_id = 100
    )
```