# Programatically move category in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an New category called Mobile(ID : 646).

I already have another category Mobile cover(ID : 516).

So i need to move all Mobile cover under Mobile category

Mobile is root category and Mobile cover is sub category

How i can move Programatically

Comment: have you tried http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84679/4564

Comment: that's product only right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example create a file named **test.php** with the below content and place it in magento root folder. Then run your site **www.yoursite.com/test.php**

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
$mobile_id = 646;
$mobile_cover_id = 516;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($mobile_cover_id);
$category->move($mobile_id, null);
?>
```

Its working for me.

Comment: ya i tried but it's not working

Comment: i put root folder but it's not working

Comment: You can set up a module and use this code. It will work.

Comment: set up module in the sense? where i have to use

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it. No need of module creation. Just follow the steps in answer